# Calling linked list function

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I have got stack with a linked list. When I call `list.push()` it works fine, but it does nothing when I do the same in funtion `init()`. What could be the problem?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNode = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.end = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def push(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = self.end = new_node
        else:
            new_node.nextNode = self.head
            self.head = new_node

#doesnt work
def init():
    list = linkedList()
    list.push("a")

init()
print(list.isEmpty()) #True

#works
list = linkedList()
list.push("a")
print(list.isEmpty()) #False
```

Comment: in the first example your 'list' object only exists within the function. Have the function return the 'list.' The code you posted would trigger an atttribute error because the builtin list doesn't have an attribute isEmpty

Answer (score 1):

Outside a function, you cannot access a local object you create inside function. Returning it makes it available:

```
def make_list():
    my_list = linkedList()
    my_list.push("a")
    return my_list

my_list = make_list()
print(my_list.isEmpty())
```

Don't use the name `list` for your objects as it shadows the builtin `list`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **RETURN** the object you make within the function, because that object '**dies**' when function ends, so there is no object there for you to look into. That's why you get empty true.

here is how you make it work:

```
def make():
    aList = linkedList()
    aList.push("a")
    return aList
```

then you would *store* whatever is return from that object:

```
some_list = make() # storing the linkedlist that make() returns into 
                   # variable called 'some_list'
print(some_list.isEmpty()) # True
```

Comment: How is this different to Mike's answer?